# Inheritance Hierarchies in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working on a database for a flying club that has a table for Flights and a table for ClubMembers. Flights, unfortunately, must be paid for by so there is a BillTo that references the ClubMember who must pay.

So far it looks like this...

```
public ClubMember
{ 
public int ID{get;set;} 
public string FirstName{get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}
}
public Flight
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public ClubMember PilotPayingTheBill{get;set;}
public double EnormousPriceToBePaid {get;set;}
}
```

Pretty simple ... but then the messy world intervenes. Sometimes the plane is flown by a mechanic for maintenance purposes. I don't want to do this the lazy way and enter the mechanic as a dummy record in the ClubMember table. The database is too new for that kind of kludge. Plus, EF has nifty ability to implement inheritance in the database, so I can keep it all nice and tidy like this:

```
public BillableEntity 
{
public int ID{get;set;} 
}

ClubMember : BillableEntity 
{ 
public string FirstName{get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}
}
NonPayingUser : BillableEntity 
{
 public string Description {get;set;}
}
public Flight
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public BillableEntity billTo{get;set;}
public double EnormousPriceToBePaid {get;set;}
}
```

With a few instructions in my fluent configuration the NonPayingUser and ClubMembers are all put in their own tables, with ID as a primary key and foreign key - a nice, concise design I was very happy with. The Billto_id column in the flights table is not null so every flight will always have a billableEntity, which will be either a clubMember or NonPayingUser.

Writing the query in TSQL is pretty easy

```
select coalesce(cm.FirstName + ' ' + cm.LastName,np.Description) as BillTo 
from Flights f
left outer join ClubMembers cm on f.billto_id = cm.ID
left outer join NonPayingUsers np on f.billto_id = np.ID
```

But doing the same thing in EF has me stumped. 
The Flight class has a BillTO property which is the parent class of BillableEntity. I can cast it to the descendant classes like this...

```
     var flights = DB.Flights
                        .Select(f => new
                        {
                            PersonName = (f.BillTo as ClubMember).FirstName + PersonName = (f.BillTo as ClubMember).LastName
                                            ,
                            OtherName = (f.BillTo as NonPayingUser).Description
                        });
```

but this produces monstrous amounts of TSQL.

One solution is just to write my own stored procs to join these tables together and use the EF classes to do all the basic CRUD on the individual tables, and that's the direction I'm leaning in. But is there a better way?

Comment: What kind of inheritance do you use? Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH), Table-Per-Type (TPT) or Table-Per-Concrete Class (TPC)?

Comment: Table per type inheritance

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of several similar questions...

EF (6, I'm looking at 7 RC1 now) always generates a huge amount of TSQL.

I think that the best answer is what is the problem of "producing monstrous amounts of TSQL"?
If you have a particular issue with a query solve that issue otherwise ignore it. You will see that in a huge percentage of cases it does not causes problem the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a calculated field in the BillableEntities table

```
    alter table BillableEntities drop column name;
    alter table BillableEntities add Name as (case when [Description] is null then LastName + ', ' + FirstName else [Description] end)
```

and then marked it as DataBaseGenerated in the BIllableEntities class.

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
```

This way the SQL produced by EF is much more manageable. Performance is good, data integrity is good too.